# Circle object isn't drawing in Zelle graphics.py window (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, zelle-graphics

Currently making a tic tac toe game in Python 3. My problem right now is that I can't get the circle to draw where the user clicks. It isn't giving me any errors, but when I click on the board it isn't drawing a circle:

```
from graphics import *
import random

def draw_board(winsizex, win):
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0)
    win.setBackground('white')
# Draw the vertical lines
    Line(Point(1,0), Point(1,3)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(2,0), Point(2,3)).draw(win)
# Draw the horizontal lines
    Line(Point(0,1), Point(3,1)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(0,2), Point(3,2)).draw(win)
    if winsizex < 100:
        win.close()
    if winsizex > 1000:
        win.close()

    def player_turns(draw_board, win):
        c = 9
    for i in range(c):
        if c%2==0:
            print("Player two take your turn")
            player1 = win.getMouse()
            play1x=player1.getX()
            play1y=player1.getY()
            #play1.draw(win)
            circ = Circle(Point(play1x, play1y), 30)
            circ.setOutline('black')
            circ.draw(win)

        else:
            print('Player one take your turn')
            play2 = win.getMouse()
            play2x=play2.getX()
            play2y=play2.getY()
            #play2.draw(win)
            circ = Circle(Point(play2x, play2y), 30)
            circ.setOutline('black')
            circ.draw(win)
        c=c-1
def main():
    winsizex = int(input("Input the size of the window: "))
    winsizey = winsizex
    win = GraphWin("Tic-Tac-Toe", winsizex, winsizey)
    draw_board(winsizex, win)
    player_turns(draw_board, win)



main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code but the one that makes the circles invisible is this:

```
win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0)
...
circ = Circle(Point(play2x, play2y), 30)
```

You changed the coordinate system to have a maximum limit of 3.0 and then drew a circle of radius 30.  The circle gets drawn, but it's so large you can't see it.  A radius of 0.3 is more realistic given the coordinate system.  Below is my rework of your example to address this and other issues:

```
from graphics import *

def draw_board(winsizex, win):
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0)

    # Draw the vertical lines
    Line(Point(1, 0), Point(1, 3)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(2, 0), Point(2, 3)).draw(win)

    # Draw the horizontal lines
    Line(Point(0, 1), Point(3, 1)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(0, 2), Point(3, 2)).draw(win)

    if not 100 < winsizex < 1000:
        win.close()

def player_turns(win):
    for c in range(1, 10):
        if c % 2 == 1:
            print("Player one take your turn")
            player1 = win.getMouse()
            circ = Circle(player1, 0.3)
        else:
            print('Player two take your turn')
            player2 = win.getMouse()
            circ = Circle(player2, 0.3)

        circ.draw(win)

winsize = int(input("Input the size of the window: "))
win = GraphWin("Tic-Tac-Toe", winsize, winsize)
draw_board(winsize, win)
player_turns(win)
```